# Clojure equivalent in Racket: (map #(procedure) (list))

Tags: dictionary, clojure, racket

I have this Clojure code:

```
(def target-data
  (map #(vector % (+ (* % %) % 1))
       (range -1.0 1.0 0.1)))
```

How do I translate it in Racket?
I tried:

```
(define (target-data)
  (map #(vector % (+ (* % %) % 1))
       (range -1.0 1.0 0.1)))
```

The `#` which appears to be a reader macro in Clojure doesn't have its equivalent in Racket. How do I create it?

Comment: I'd suggest describing what the Clojure code and syntax in question do for folks who know only Racket but not Clojure. Might also tag the Racket question Scheme.

Comment: that said, `#(...)` in Clojure is a shortcut for lambda, and scheme *does* have lambdas.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As mentioned, the `#(...)` form in Clojure is just a shorthand syntax for `(fn ...)`, which is called `(lambda ...)` in Racket. If you want it to be shorter, you can also use `(λ ...)`, and DrRacket actually has a shortcut for inserting the `λ` character.

Using `λ`, your code would look like this:

```
(define (target-data)
  (map (λ (x) (vector x (+ (* x x) x 1)))
       (range -1.0 1.0 0.1)))
```

---

If you want Clojure-like shorthand, `#lang racket` does not support anything like that out of the box, but Racket is flexible enough to add it as a reader macro. There are a couple different packages that implement Clojure-like function shorthand, including one I have written called `curly-fn`, which is very similar to the Clojure shorthand.

To use it, first install the `curly-fn` package:

```
raco pkg install curly-fn
```

Then add `curly-fn` as a “meta language” at the top of your file:

```
#lang curly-fn racket
```

This will extend the `racket` language with the function shorthand, which looks like this:

```
#{vector % (+ (* % %) % 1)}
```

Notably, it is nearly identical to the Clojure syntax, but since `#(...)` is already used in Racket for vector literals, `curly-fn` uses `#{...}` instead. Therefore, your program would look like this:

```
(define (target-data)
  (map #{vector % (+ (* % %) % 1)}
       (range -1.0 1.0 0.1)))
```

Since `curly-fn` is a meta-language, it can also be used with any other language that uses s-expression syntax, such as `#lang curly-fn racket/base` or even `#lang curly-fn typed/racket`.

The `curly-fn` shorthand is also a little bit more flexible than the Clojure equivalent—notably, it can also be used as a simple shorthand for `curry` if no arguments are used—and you can find all the details in [the package documentation](http://docs.racket-lang.org/curly-fn/).

Answer (score 2):

You might be looking for lambdas.

```
(define target-data
  (map (lambda (x) (vector x (+ (* x x) x 1)))
       (range -1.0 1.0 0.1)))
```

This seems to give the same result for me as the Clojure code.

https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/lambda.html